# How do i use recursive function in haskell to find nth element of a list? and more

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

i've started studying functional programming in Haskell recently and was given some problems to solve, it asks to make your own versions of some system function for lists using recursion and basic system functions. the functions i need to write is:

- `!!` (nth item in a list)
- `append` (joining lists together)
- `subst` (substitution) e.g. `subst 'x' 'y' ['q','x','r','x','s']` ~> `['q','y','r','x','y','s']`
- `intersection`  e.g. `intersection [2,5,7] [9,7,3,5]` ~> `[5,7]`
- `union`  union   e.g  `union [2,5,7] [9,7,3,5]` ~> `[2,5,7,9,3]`
- `reverse`  e.g. `reverse [4,5,6,7]` ~> `[7,6,5,4]`

I started with the first one and wrote a definition like this:

```
nthelement :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> a
```

in imperative language i would make a counter variable (say `i`) and use system function `tail` to remove first element of list until `i = n`. But as I learned that in functional you can only do constants I can't think of a way to decide when to stop recurring and return the element rather then recuring `tail` function till the list is empty.

Please help me to figure this out. Any help on doing first function or any of them would be very nice. Thanks.

Comment: First start with an accurate type signature. `nthelement` does not need `Eq a`, and it doesn't take an `a` next to the list. Example use would be `nthelement ['a','c','b'] 1 ~> 'c'`

Comment: Try with pattern matching and standard structural recursion. Do not use `head` or `tail`.

Comment: i've mant to write Ord a. As i understand it:
Ord a => means that arguments to this function must be of ordered type (Int's , Float's but not Strings?)

 [a] -> a -> a  means that function will take one list argument , one (Int/Float) and will return Int/Float (Ord) 

nthelement [1,2,3] 1   would return   2

Am i wrong here?

Comment: Actually it is `xs <<!!>> n = head . drop n $ xs`

Comment: @EasternDude: No, `Ord a` means that `a`s are comparable - `<`, `==`, `>`. What you meant is a `Num` (arithmetic operations). What you actually need is an integral type, such as `Integer` or `Int`. And the basic problem you had that you've specified the index to be of the same type as the list elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm only providing a general answer here to one of the questions you raised. I'm hoping this will help you understand the general problem better and come up with solutions to your specific problems/tasks.

> in imperative language i would make a counter variable (say i) and use system function tail to remove first element of list until i = n. But as I learned that in functional you can only do constants I can't think of a way to decide when to stop recurring and return the element rather then recuring tail function till the list is empty.

you can always "simulate" a for loop with a state variable and breaking out of the loop using recursion:

Python:

```py
def foo(xs):
    state = initial_state
    for x in xs:
        state = make_new_state(x, state)
        if not condition(state, x):
            break
    return state
```

in the equivalent Haskell code, you would use an inner function with an extra argument for the state. You can also expose the extra argument on `foo` but normally you don't want to expose that to the callers of `foo`:

```hs
foo xs = go initialState xs
  where go []     state = state
        go (x:xs) state = if not (condition state x)
                          then state
                          else go xs (makeNewState x state)
```

for many algorithms, breaking out of the loop is not needed at all, in which case the "pattern" becomes:

```hs
foo xs = go initialState xs
  where go []     state = state
        go (x:xs) state = go xs (makeNewState x state)
```

where `makeNewState` is the logic you execute at each step (and it doesn't have to be in a separate function, of course).

For the latter case, there are some generic functions `foldr` and `foldl` and `foldl'`, such that:

```hs
foo xs = foldr makeNewState initialState xs
```

---

**Furthermore:** there are also things like the [State monad](https://wiki.haskell.org/State_Monad), which let you write imperative logic in a pure manner, but it's best to understand things like "raw" recursion and folds first, and only then move on to things like monads and explicit state.

Comment: Thanks, ive managed to do most of problems in my question.  However,  im struggling to write a simple fucntion to create an array, even in most simplistic form. To start with i want  to give a function argument n and get an array [1...n]. I tought it woul be piece of cake but this dosent work:
makeArray :: Int -> [a]
makeArray n  = [1..n]

can someone explain me why it dosent work and how to fix it?

Comment: the type of your `makeArray` should be `Int -> [Int]`. and these are called _lists_ not arrays; arrays in Haskell are a separate notion.

Comment: alright, the what would be type definition for this function that finds right triangles whose sides are <= 10 and perimeter == 24? rightTriangles = [ (a,b,c) | c <- [1..10], b <- [1..c], a <- [1..b], a^2 + b^2 == c^2, a+b+c == 24]

Comment: dude, that's a totally different question. but just do `:t rightTriangles` on GHCi and it'll tell you the type it has inferred. and it's not a function; it's just a constant list. the type could be either `[(Int, Int, Int)]` if you declare it to be that, but GHC will infer something more general, as typically.

Comment: Thanks! yeah i know this is a different question and its not a function i just didn't want to ask a new question for something simple like this. I understand the basics of haskell now except for those nasty type declarations, they're hard to figure out for me sometimes :/ I noticed that haskell interprets the type by itself and all of the functions i tested so dar work even without type declaration. Is it generally o.k. to write functions without declaring a type? or is it considered to be a bad practice among advanced haskell programmers?

Comment: top level functions should generally have an explicit type annotation, but it's up to you, of course. and again, just use GHCi to have Haskell generate the type signature for you, and then copy-paste that to your `.hs` file. you can also then adjust the signature to be, say, less polymorphic (generic) or not polymorphic at all (monomorphic). for example, if you set up your project using `stack`, just run `stack ghci`  and then type e.g. `:t rightTriangles`.

Answer (score 9):

(As @Bergi correctly notes in the comments, you should check that your signature and the one of `!!` in the standard libraries coincide!)

Instead of thinking of the `i` in `list !! i` as a *variable*, think of it as a function *parameter*. Then, consider the different cases of this parameter, and decide what your `!!` function should do in each case. Then, think about what options your list parameter `list` has, and how you should consider them:

Expanding all the potential options for `i` and `list` gives us the following:

```
nthelement :: [a] -> Integer -> a
nthelement [] 0 = -- ?
nthelement [] i = -- ?
nthelement (l:ls) 0 = -- ?
nthelement (l:ls) n = -- ?
```

The remaining functions can be written by following a similar strategy.

Comment: +1 for identifying the relevant base cases, and for not giving a complete solution                                                                                             :-)

Comment: if i want my function to only work on lists of numbers ( i know this dosen't make much sense, its for learning purposes only) would i define function like this?:
`nthelement :: Num a => [a] -> Int -> a`

Comment: @EasternDude Yep, that would restrict the elements of the list to numeric types. You could make things even more generic with `nthelement :: (Num a, Integral i) => [a] -> i -> a`, which would allow any integer-like type to index the list.

Comment: I've made a case for non-empty list:

`nthelement :: [a] -> Int -> a

nthelement (h:t) x = if (x==0) then h else (nthelement t x)`

and it works if  I choose 0th element e.g nthelement [1,2,3] 0  return '1' but if i try 1 or 2'nd e.g. nthelement [1,2,3] 1 gives an error:
Non-exhaustive patterns in function nthelement

Comment: @EasternDude you can avoid the check on `x`, since you can also pattern match against numbers (as I've done above). You should check if your function is correct: what is the result of `nthelement [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] 1`? (You should do this by explicitly writing out what the function returns!) Is it what you expect?

Comment: Update! my current function:  
`nthelement :: [a] -> Int -> a  nthelement (h:t) 0 = h  nthelement (h:t) x = nthelement t (x-1)`

and it works! yay! But still, i have no idea what to do in cases when list is empy

Comment: Matching pairs of `{-` and `-}` form multiline comments.

Comment: As for the empty list case, you cannot necessarily produce an element of type `a`. There are two common solutions to this: one is simply to blow up (which is what `!!` does) and the other is to use an error-handling type, such as `Maybe`.

Comment: no, not in haskell, here in Stackoverflow...   i cant start new lines when commenting, so annoying. Help says: End a line with two spaces to add a <br/> linebreak. it dosnt work...

Comment: @EasternDude, it's almost never useful or wise to add a constraint that's not necessary. It *can* be useful in some cases to make something less polymorphic by fixing a specific type. So `nthChar :: [Char] -> Int -> Char` might be useful in some contexts, but `nthNum :: Num n => [n] -> Int -> n` is silly.